# Add the text in between two text using php file handling

Tags: php

My question we have file handling in php.In file handling we have create file,write file and update file.if i create the text file using php file handling and write into the file some Hello guys and close the file.I want to update the file but this time while update file i want to add the text in between Hello and guys.For example Hello hii guys.or guys word will be overwrtten by speed.Hello speed.

thanks please help me

Comment: before saving manipulate the text..whats the issue ??

Comment: if i update the text file using php new text always written over end of the file not in between which i want

Comment: Is it *always* going to be "Hello guys", or you just want to throw text in between two totally random works?

Answer (score 1):

you can append text at last using below link or any other option
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible even in any language, you have to read file in buffer then do changes as you want and after that write down in file. On the other hand You can append text at last.